# Control an embedded flash movie's playback in HTML/php

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash

I am using an embedded flash movie in my web page. I would like to show some alerts on the page when the movie has played for x seconds, pause the movie while the user views and dismisses the alert and start playing the movie again after that (or the user can press the play button, not important)

The important parts being - the app being able to find out if x secs worth of movie has played, pausing the movie then and showing an alert.

Is this possible using a php/javascript code within the web page? Or will I have to do this within the flash movie itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExternalInterface](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) is what you need.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I assume will have to put in functions in the script to stop/start the movie? Or can I stop/start the movie from the javascript itself?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to write a few lines on the movie, so it knows what to do when a command comes from the outside. Should be fairly simple though.